# Problem in C with the generation of a matrix that should contain unmatched (previously) item

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix, integer, combinations

Ok i`ll minimize my problem

i`ve a matrix of the type

```
int nitem = 20; // imagine that the items are numbers from 1 to 20
int nmatch = nitem-1; // because every item can have 19 combination with other items (1 - 2, 1 - 3, etc..)
int matrix[nmatch*(nitem/2)][2]; //in this case 190 row because every cycle will put in this array 10 match that aren`t done before.
```

now i`ve to put in the matrix array element of the type

```
matrix = {{1 , 2},{3 , 4},{5 , 6}, etc..}
```

But from row 0 to 9 (10 to 19, 20 to 29 etc...) i want to put numbers that appears only 1 time in the actual 10 row.
Obtaining a result like:

```
matrix = {{1 , 2}, {3 , 4}, {5 , 6}, {7 , 8}, {9 , 10}, {11 , 12}, {13 , 14}, {15 , 16}, {17 , 18}, {19 , 20}}
```

On my second cycle i want to match items that aren`t matched before (the entire couple not the single item) and obtain a matrix of the type:

```
matrix = {{1 , 2}, {3 , 4}, {5 , 6}, {7 , 8}, {9 , 10}, {11 , 12}, {13 , 14}, {15 , 16}, {17 , 18}, {19 , 20}, {2 , 3}, {4 , 5}, {6 , 7}, {8 , 9}, {10 , 11}, {12 , 13}, {14 , 15}, {16 , 17}, {18 , 19}, {20 , 21}}
```

And I’d like to do this 19 time until the end of all my possible combination (and the end of the matrix obv)..

I tried to code it 2 times but my code its too big and contain a lot of variable that i use in my program so i can't post my logic error but i'll be very grateful to to anyone who helps me with this little code.

I also use this tecnique to write at the right position in this matrix

```
int cycle = 1;
int * ptrcycle = &cycle;
...
void myfunction(int * ptr, int matrix[][2], int nitem){
    for(int i = (ptr-1)*(nitem/2); i < ptr*(nitem/2); i++){
       do my things...
    }
*ptr = *ptr+1
}
```

so every time i call my cycle, imagine at `cycle = 3`, i'll have `i = 20` and `i < 30` (both correct).

Please help meee :(

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: And try it on Godbolt too ...